# how to apply a function that returns a dataframe to each row of another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

i have the following function which takes a row and return a dataframe `ld_coefs_df_long` , i am not sure if function syntax is correct or not :

```
 def apply_calc_coef (row):
   device_id = row['deviceId']
   sound_filename = row['filename'] 
   sound_fullpath = os.path.join(basepath, device_id, sound_filename)
   offset = row['offset']
   telemetry_id = row['telemetry_id']


   fs,data = wavfile.read(sound_fullpath)
   ld_coefs_df = calc_ld_coefs(data, fs, offset=offset, win_len=2000, ndeg=12)

   ld_coefs_df_long = pd.melt(ld_coefs_df, id_vars=['time'] , var_name='series_type' )
   ld_coefs_df_long['telemetry_id'] = telemetry_id
   ld_coefs_df_long.rename(columns={"time": "t_seconds"})

   return ld_coefs_df_long // is a dataframe
```

i need to apply this function to each row of a  dataframe called `ds_telemetry_pd` and stack the results ( which is a dataframe for each row)  together to have anew dataframe , using following syntax:

```
 ds_telemetry_pd.apply(lambda x:  apply_calc_coef(x))
```

apparently i am not in a good direction, as either of my function or the way i apply t or both of them are incorrect.

EDIT:
 when i use `ds_telemetry_pd.apply(apply_calc_coef, axis=1)` i get the following error :

```
 `cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 14400`
```

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3171623043129929> in <module>()
----> 1 ds_telemetry_pd.apply(apply_calc_coef, axis=1)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, args, **kwds)
   4150                     if reduce is None:
   4151                         reduce = True
-> 4152                     return self._apply_standard(f, axis, reduce=reduce)
   4153             else:
   4154                 return self._apply_broadcast(f, axis)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _apply_standard(self, func, axis, ignore_failures, reduce)
   4263                 index = None
   4264 
-> 4265             result = self._constructor(data=results, index=index)
   4266             result.columns = res_index
   4267 

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    264                                  dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
    265         elif isinstance(data, dict):
--> 266             mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    267         elif isinstance(data, ma.MaskedArray):
    268             import numpy.ma.mrecords as mrecords

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _init_dict(self, data, index, columns, dtype)
    400             arrays = [data[k] for k in keys]
    401 
--> 402         return _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
    403 
    404     def _init_ndarray(self, values, index, columns, dtype=None, copy=False):

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _arrays_to_mgr(arrays, arr_names, index, columns, dtype)
   5401 
   5402     # don't force copy because getting jammed in an ndarray anyway
-> 5403     arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
   5404 
   5405     # from BlockManager perspective

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _homogenize(data, index, dtype)
   5712                 v = lib.fast_multiget(v, oindex.values, default=NA)
   5713             v = _sanitize_array(v, index, dtype=dtype, copy=False,
-> 5714                                 raise_cast_failure=False)
   5715 
   5716         homogenized.append(v)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in _sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure)
   2950             raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional')
   2951         else:
-> 2952             subarr = _asarray_tuplesafe(data, dtype=dtype)
   2953 
   2954     # This is to prevent mixed-type Series getting all casted to

/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py in _asarray_tuplesafe(values, dtype)
    390             except ValueError:
    391                 # we have a list-of-list
--> 392                 result[:] = [tuple(x) for x in values]
    393 
    394     return result

ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 14400 ```
````

Comment: on which line you get error, paste full stack trace.

Comment: @vb_rises i made an edit

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  I'd recommend you prepare a [MCVE] if you want better answers.

Comment: @Krrr basically i want to apply that function to every row in a dataframe.

Comment: @chessosapiens: what is the shape of your `ds_telemetry_pd` dataframe?

Comment: @vb_rises (3, 18)

Comment: @chessosapiens the problem is inside your `apply_calc_coef` function. you need to debug it line by line. probably how you apply is correct (with axis = 1), first 5 lines are also correct inside your function, but you need to check lines after it. debug it line by line.

Comment: @vb_rises it works when i run it line by line, and it works remember the function returns a datafraem not a series

Comment: try something like this `df = pd.DataFrame()` (empty dataframe). And if your function returns a dataframe, df_list = [data for data in ds_telemetry_pd.apply(apply_calc_coef, axis=1)], basically create a list of dataframes. Then do `pd.concat([df] + df_list, ignore_index=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Your result will be a Serie of DataFrames. In order to transform them in one DataFrame, you can do something like :

```
pd.concat(ds_telemetry_pd.apply(apply_calc_coef, axis=1).tolist(), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: it returns an error :` ('deviceId', 'occurred at index telemetry_id')`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me :

```
 chunks=[]
 for i in range(ds_telemetry_pd.shape[0]):
   row = ds_telemetry_pd.iloc[i,:]
   t_df = apply_calc_coef2(row)
   chunks.append(t_df)
 ld_coef_df=  pd.concat(chunks, ignore_index=True)
```